# Tem como bloquear a Seta do campo DATE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teria algum jeito de bloquear essa setinha ai ?

Comment: Isso aí parece ser javascript, pode colocar o código que gera esse input.

Comment: Sim, muda o _type_ do input. Provavelmente tens um `input type="date"` muda para `input type="text"` e coloca um datepicker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está procurando pelo `webkit-inner-spin-button`. Inclusive você consegue desativar o `Calendar Picker` se quiser. Sobre a utilização de `::placeholders` ser suportado, dê uma olhada aqui: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder

```js
dateInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyIdentifier == "Down") {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
}, false);
```

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.semPicker::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="caixa">
    <input type="date" /> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="date" class="semPicker" />
</div>
```

Comment: Interessante `+1`, seria bom indicar em que browsers é que isso funciona.

Comment: @Sergio Feito :)

Comment: Mt obrigado Funcionou muito bem :)